# HostedService not being registered as a singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, .net-5

I'm using `Autofac` for my DI. I'm registering an `IHostedService` as follows:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyHostedService>()
    .As<IMyHostedService>()
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

I also tried:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyHostedService>()
    .As<IMyHostedService>()
    .SingleInstance();
```

`IMyHostedService` inherits from `IHostedService` adding a couple of extra methods that I need to call from a controller.

Both registrations above are not registering the service correctly. When I pass `IMyHostedService` into my controllers constructor, a new instance is resolved everytime. I confirmed this by writing a log entry in the service's constructor.

Why am I not getting the same instance everytime?

Comment: You didn't post any code that registers a hosted service. `AddHostedService` does more than just register the service as a singleton, it also adds it to the list of hosted services that are started when the host itself starts and terminated when the host shuts down. If you integrate Autofac and .NET Core DI properly you shouldn't have to register hosted services with Autofac as well

Comment: BTW whether a hosted service is transient or singleton is essentially an implementation detail that has changed in the past. In the early days a hosted service was registered as a Transient that didn't get disposed until the host terminated. In .NET 5 and 6 it's a singleton.

Comment: Shouldn't Autofac handle the registration. The service is definitely being started on start and stopped on termination.

Comment: I closed this question because the same author has effectively the same question but phrased differently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69896164/backgroundservice-starting-twice).