# BackgroundService starting twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, .net-5, background-service

I have the following background service:

```
public class MyHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ITaskQueue taskQueue;
    private readonly ILifetimeScope scope;
    private readonly IMapper mapper;
    private readonly IHubContext<MainHub, IMainHub> hubContext;
    private readonly List<ConnectionString> connectionStrings;
    private readonly ILogger<MyHostedService> logger;
    private readonly Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();

    public MyHostedService(
        ITaskQueue taskQueue,
        ILifetimeScope scope,
        IMapper mapper,
        IHubContext<MainHub, IMainHub> hubContext,
        IOptions<List<ConnectionString>> connectionStrings,
        ILogger<MyHostedService> logger)
    {
        this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
        this.scope = scope;
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.hubContext = hubContext;
        this.connectionStrings = connectionStrings.Value;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(MyHostedService)} {guid} is starting.");
        return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(MyHostedService)} is running.");
        await BackgroundProcessing(stoppingToken);
    }

    private async Task BackgroundProcessing(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var workItem = await taskQueue.DequeueAsync(stoppingToken);
            //Process workItem here...
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(MyHostedService)} is stopping.");
        await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

And the `Autofac` registration is:

```
builder.RegisterType<TaskQueue>()
    .As<ITaskQueue>()
    .SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<MyHostedService>()
    .As<IHostedService>()
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

This is the only registration I'm doing. I'm not using `AddHostedService` in `Startup.cs`. When I start the app, the service is started twice as shown in this log:

[image: Log]

Why does the service start twice?

**UPDATE**

If I comment the registration for `MyHostedService`, the service is somehow still registered but at least it starts only once.

If I'm not registering the service using `Autofac` and I'm definitely not using the default DI, how is the service being registered/found/started?

Comment: You are creating an instance per Dependency. Could it be the case that you are accessing it through DI in multiple places?

This is described quite well here: https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-lifetime-scope

Comment: No. The service is started when the app starts and I'm not using the service anywhere so far.

Comment: Could it be that it's because I'm inheriting from `BackgroundService` instead from `IHostedService`?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be an issue. BackgroundService just implements some functionality Start/Stop etc. for convenience and should be used - if you don't require any specific implementations.

Comment: And the TaskQueue doesn't referencing to it as well?

Comment: "If I comment the registration for MyHostedService, the service is somehow still registered but at least it starts only once." Are you sure you are showing all the code? You must have some assembly scanning going on that is registering the hosted service, and then when you call it explicitly you are registering it again.

Comment: `IHostedServce` are different animals. You are treating them as if they are the same as a typical `Transient`, `Singleton` or `Scoped` service. So in essence, you are registering it yourself, then the WebHost is registering it because it has the `IHostedService` interface. You should remove your registration of the `IHostedService` and register it using `service.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>()` in your `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`. There is some speculation in this comment, but I am pretty sure this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your autofac registration is

```
builder.RegisterType<MyHostedService>()
    .As<IHostedService>()
    .SingleInstance();
```

and remove `AddHostedService`.